# XQuartz was recently upgraded. Some apps that used X11 no longer work

Tags: macos, high-sierra, x11, xquartz

Recently XQuartz was automatically updated on my Mac running High Sierra. Now the apps that used X11 no longer work. I also noticed that if I run XQuartz by double-clicking on the app it opens but immediately shuts down after about 1 second.

Does anyone know why my apps requiring X11 no longer work?

Comment: Euther they need updating or XQuartz is not correctly installed - solution revert back or correctly install XQ.

Comment: try control-click to open XQuartz if that doest work copy this to the terminal:   sudo spctl --master-disable , then open again with right click open

Comment: @SolarMike, I'm confused by your comment. I have the latest version of XQuartz.  It was automatically updated and the older version was deleted I suppose.  Normally I use XQuartz by just clicking on the icon. I know nothing about installing it first.  Do you know if XQuartz has an installer?

Comment: @Junme, I tried both suggestions but neither worked. thanks for the help though.

Comment: So, do the other apps need updating...

Comment: I have latest apps for at least two of the apps that no longer run.  thanks..

Comment: @SolarMike, Sorry about my initial response. The is an installer for XQuartz and I ran the most recent version. Its had no noticeable effect.  Two of the apps that no longer run are Gnuplot and Nedit. Both ran fine a week ago.

Comment: @SolarMike, @ Monomeeth, My question was ill-conceived. XQuartz has not been upgraded to my knowledge. The latest version was dated 2016. Is there a way to delete my question and ask another one that explains better my problem. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: the only other thing I can suggest is to reinstall XQuartz good luck

Comment: I thought of that too and tried it. No luck.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: "recently"? Where did you get the update from? xquartz looks dead in the water dev-wise for me, last release 2016? Which version did you install and which version was replaced?

Comment: I download and installed the 2016 version. It was the same as the version I had but I installed it anyway to see if it would have any effect.  It didn't.